# Adding a maven library into Netbeans Web Project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jwt

I have a Netbeans Web Project created via Netbeans project creation wizard. The Project is almost complete, being used in testing so not a new one. This is a `REST` API actually.  Anyway now we need to implement `JWT` into this, so we looked into this famous library - https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

The problem is that it is totally maven based, can't find a `jar` file to download and implement. In this case, how can we integrate this into our application?

Comment: A quick Google of `"java-jwt jar download"` leads quite quickly to the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.1.0)

Comment: @AJNeufeld: Agree. I also found it via search.maven.org. Anyway seriously wondering how to add a maven into a existing project without totally destroying it....

Comment: @PeakGen Just to be sure, have you seen "Download JAR" link on this page?

Comment: @defaultlocale: I searched by `java-jwt` then it gave me results. I was searching for `com.auth0` written library, there was a link to download in the table.

Comment: @PeakGen Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. [Maven repository page for java-jwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.1.0) has a [Download (JAR)](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/auth0/java-jwt/3.1.0/java-jwt-3.1.0.jar) link. So you can download the JAR from the repository and use it in your project without maven.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Yes, sure!

Comment: @defaultlocale: anyway, when using it, the dependencies are not available!

Comment: @PeakGen yes, actually, one of the benefits of a build system (maven, or, in this case, Gradle) is an automatic dependency management. Without it, you'll need to handle them one-by-one manually. List of "compile dependencies" in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.1.0) might help, but, in some cases, you'll need to go deep to get them all.